# How to check behavior in py.test fixtures?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

In C# I can use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) to create mock objects, which I can use to check if something got called. In this example, I will check if the `MyModelClass.Bar()` function calls `IMyInterface.Foo()` at least once:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestBar() {
    var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
    var systemUnderTest = new MyModelClass(mock.Object);
    systemUnderTest.Bar();

    // Let the test fail, if Foo() was not called at least once
    mock.Verify(x => x.Foo(), Times.AtLeastOnce());
}
```

Programming in Python using [pytest](https://pytest.org/), what is the best way to achieve the same? Or should I use other testing frameworks for things like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered [Mock](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock), a testing library which does what I want:

```py
from mock import Mock

def test_bar():
    mock = Mock()
    system_under_test = MyModelClass(mock)
    system_under_test.bar()
    mock.foo.assert_called_once_with()
```

Comment: ... and you can take a look to https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing to mimic the interface. By the same framework you can either patch exist implementation by mocks. You can find tons of QA on SO about this topic :)

Comment: Note there is also [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) which makes it easier to use mocks and e.g. takes care of resetting them after each test.